# TSQL Query to calculate percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables :

- Table A (`id as int, M as int,...`)
- Table B (`Aid as int , P as int,...`)

There is a relation between A and B on `A.id = B.Aid`. Parent table is A and child table is B which means one row in A may have multiple rows in B.

I need to write a T-SQL query which returns the following information:

- some columns of the A and the related rows from B
- and also calculate this `(M / Sum(p)) as 'Percent'` for each row of A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT
  a.M,
  (a.M / pSum)
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT aid, SUM(p) pSum
  FROM TableB
  GROUP BY aid
) b ON A.id = B.Aid;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1231/1)

**Update:** If you want to return more that one column from the `tableb`, with the sum of `p` for each parent record in the `tablea`, you can join the `TableB` on more time like so:

```
SELECT
  a.M,
  b.p,
  (a.M / groupedb.pSum)
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b ON A.id = B.Aid
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT aid, SUM(p) pSum
  FROM TableB
  GROUP BY aid
) groupedb ON A.id = groupedb.Aid;
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1231/2)

But this will make the calculations on the sum coming from the `tableB` redundant for each parent record in the `tableA` redundant for each record of the table `B`.

Comment: Mahmoud thanks for your quick response. your suggestion is working fine. i just have another question. what if i decide to return more columns from TableB? because there is Group BY it won't let me to return more columns unless i used them in group by or in aggregate function

Comment: @aliakhbarizadeh - You can do this. See my edit. I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but try it.

Comment: you were right it has some redundant but if i use top(1) then i'll have only one record with details that i need

Comment: @aliakhbarizadeh - You can use `TOP(1)` or you can use another aggregate function to get only the `MAX` value of some row.